# In how many ways can you withdraw $\$50$ from an ATM

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In how many ways can you withdraw $50\rm USD$ from an ATM using $1, 2, 5, 10$, and $20$ bills? The preferred method should not use a generating function.

I tried using just the create function, but my professor told me that's not how we're supposed to solve it, and now I'm stuck.
I tried to use something like $$20x_1+10x_2+5x_3+2x_4+x_4=50$$
but in this case i can't proceed
in my first attempt i used Generating function
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\frac{1}{1-x},B(x)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-x^2},C(x)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{5n}=\frac{1}{1-x^5}
\ldots$$
then:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^a(x) =A(x)\\ 
(1-x^2)S^{AB}(x)=S^A(x) \\ 
(1-x^5)S^{ABC}(x)=S^A(x)\\
(1-x^{10})S^{ABCD}(x)=S^A(x)\\
(1-x^{20})S^{ABCDE}(x)=S^A(x)\\
\end{array}
\right.  $$
and i got to this point
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^a_n=a_n=1\\ 
S^{AB}_n=S^A+S^{AB}_{n-2}\\ 
S^{ABC}_n=S^{AB}_N+S^{ABC}_{N-5}\\
S^{ABCD}_n=S^{ABC}+S^{ABCD}_{N-10}\\
S^{ABCDE}_n=S^{ABCD}+S^{ABCDE}_{N-20}\\
\end{array}
\right.  $$
but he said we don't have generating functions in our curriculum, and left me without any further informations. But we had them in Inhomogeneous recurrence. Now even I don't know
About combinatorics in my syllabus:

> Methods of counting combinatorial objects. Binary and polynomial coefficients. Combinatorial identities. The drawer principle. Basic principles and laws of conversion: the principle of bijection, the principle of addition and multiplication, and the principle of inclusions and exclusions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You would need to put that attempt into your post rather than the comments and type the math using Mathjax, and try to explain everything you tried in as much detail as possible. Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What techniques *are* in your curriculum?

Comment: See the answer of Nick Haliday [here](https://www.quora.com/How-many-ways-can-you-make-change-for-a-50-bill-using-only-5-10-and-20-bills#UXBfN) ; explained with ... generating functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to figure out how many ways to draw $\$50$ from an ATM. The banknotes we have are $\$1$, $\$2$, $\$5$, $\$10$, and $\$20$.

Consider the series
$$a_{n} = 1,1,1,1,1...$$
$$b_{n} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n \equiv 1 \mod 2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
$$c_{n} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n \equiv 1 \mod 5 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
$$d_{n} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n \equiv 1 \mod 10 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
$$e_{n} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n \equiv 1 \mod 20 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

We can represent them as generating functions:
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},B(x)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-x^2},C(x)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{5n}=\frac{1}{1-x^5}, \text{etc.}$$
respectively.

Let's multiply $$S^{AB}(x)=A(x)B(x)$$
After multiplying we get:
$$A(x)B(x) = (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n) (\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^{2n})= (1+x+x^2+x^3...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6...)= 1+x+x^2+x^2+x^3+x^3+x^4+x^4+x^4+...$$

We cannot find the formula for this sequence, but we can extract some of its first elements
$$2x^2, 2x^3, 3x^4...$$
$$S_n^{AB}=(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,...)$$

This series answers the question of how many ways can we form $n$ dollars using one and two dollar bills.

Since we could multiply two series together, why not multiply all of them? We'll get something like this:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^A(x) =A(x)\\ 
S^{AB}(x)=S^A(x)*B(x) \\ 
S^{ABC}(x)=S^{AB}(x)=C(x)\\
S^{ABCD}(x)=S^{ABC}(x)=D(x)\\
S^{ABCDE}(x)=S^{ABCD}(x)=E(x)\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Since these are ordinary geometric series, we can interpret them as:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^a(x) =A(x)\\ 
S^{AB}(x)=S^A(x)*\frac{1}{1-x^2}/(1-x^2) \\ 
S^{ABC}(x)=S^A(x)\frac{1}{1-x^5}/(1-x^5)\\
S^{ABCD}(x)=S^A(x)\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}/(1-x^{10})\\
S^{ABCDE}(x)=S^A(x)\frac{1}{1-x^{20}}/(1-x^{20})\\
\end{array}
\right.  $$
And we're left with something like this
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^A(x) =A(x)\\ 
(1-x^2)S^{AB}(x)=S^A(x) \\ 
(1-x^5)S^{ABC}(x)=S^A(x)\\
(1-x^{10})S^{ABCD}(x)=S^A(x)\\
(1-x^{20})S^{ABCDE}(x)=S^A(x)\\
\end{array}
\right.  $$
$$$$
which after further transformations gives us:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S^A_n=a_n=1\\ 
S^{AB}_n=S^A_n+S^{AB}_{n-2}\\ 
S^{ABC}_n=S^{AB}_n+S^{ABC}_{n-5}\\
S^{ABCD}_n=S^{ABC}_n+S^{ABCD}_{n-10}\\
S^{ABCDE}_n=S^{ABCD}_n+S^{ABCDE}_{n-20}\\
\end{array}
\right.  $$
And we can just use table to compute this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCYyh.png)

I don't think this solution is very elegant, but it (I think) works.